# How to use input from user to increase the range of integers on a variable named game_board

Tags: python

I apologize if this if is not easy to understand. I am working on perfecting my questions as well as my skill with Python. Thanks for all help.

The tic tac toe game with dynamic size changes is selected by the user input[image: In the picture you can see the numbers stop at 3].

My question is, how do I make the top row column reference numbers dynamic.
Right now they are static.

The following code is where I need help:

```
for count, row in enumerate(game_map):
```

In the "for count, row in enumerate(game_map)" how do I add "column in this line of code?

Or do I need to write a different line of code in the block of code?

Bellow is the block of code and it's clause for the gameboard:

```
def game_board(game_map, player=0, row=0, column=0, just_display=False):
    try:
        if game_map[row][column] != 0: #Done
            print("This spot taken try again.") #Done
            return game_map, False #Done
        print("   0  1  2")
        if not just_display:
            game_map[row][column] = player
        for count, row in enumerate(game_map):
            print(count, row)
        return game_map, True
```

This is what I tied to do 
Resulting with this output

```
try:
        if game_map[row][column] != 0: #Done
            print("This spot taken try again.") #Done
            return game_map, False #Done
        #print("   0  1  2")
        if not just_display:
            game_map[row][column] = player
        for count, row, column, in enumerate(game_map):
            print(count, row)
        return game_map, True
```

[image: Error reads: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)]

Comment: Thank you in advance. I am learning how to work with Python so I'm looking to learn as I get the answer.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "Learning to program with Python 3" is not a problem definition -- your *question* must be self-contained.  Also see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  As posted, we don't know what you want or what you're getting.  We're not going to experiment with your code to reverse-engineer those missing items: that's *your* job as poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `print("   0  1  2")` with `print("   " + " ".join(map(str, range(len(game_map)))))`.
This is taking the length of `game_map`, which is how many numbers you want and creating a range out of it. Then you convert all the `int`s in the range into `str`s with `map` and join them together with spaces. Then add the spaces at the beginning!